# Cast result to custom class with System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

I am trying to typecast result to custom class with [`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) but I am getting exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]' to type 'MyClass

My code is:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int LangId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

var fields = "new(LangId AS LangId,TranslateId AS GroupId)";
context.Table.Select(fields).ToDynamicListAsync<MyClass>();
```

Did I wrongly understand what should generic method `ToDynamicListAsync` do, or I have another error in code somewhere else?

Can I do that? (typecast `dynamic[]` result to `custom_object[]`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can also use this code?

```
var rows = await context.Table.Select<MyClass>(fields).ToDynamicListAsync<MyClass>();
```

This extension method is also defined in [DynamicQueryableExtensions.cs](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/DynamicQueryableExtensions.cs#L1187)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do some weird thing with reflection and then I stumbled on solution:

```
var rows = await context.Table.Select(typeof(MyClass), fields).ToDynamicListAsync<MyClass>();
```

Hope it helps someone else.